# MS Access Import Error. Locked\Protected Cells in Excel File

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have VBA Code in my Access 2007 database which imports an Excel file. The file was created in Excel 2007 and saved as a .xls.
The import was working perfectly every time but now I have an issue.

Previously, the sheet was protected but I could select the cells.

Now, the sheet is protected but I cannot 'Select locked cells'.

Even if I use the wizard to import the data I get a message which says:

'The wizard is unable to access information in the file [file name]. Please check that the file exists and is in the correct format.'

So it appears as though Access cannot read the file if the cells are locked.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or been able to import an Excel sheet into Access where the cells are locked and password protected (you can't even click\select then). This level of protection is now necessary so I can't ask the user to turn it off.

I have too much code to post but basically I am using the: DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ImportSpecName, to import the data.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can see the data then you can also import it. To test that just create a new & empty Excel file and enter into a cell a reference to the other file such as `='[\\Path\To\Protected\File\FileName.xls]Sheet1'!A1`. Enter this formula manually and don't try to select the cell in the other file to generate the line for you. If it works then you can simply copy the formula accross the entire sheet and you get a *carbon copy* of the sheet in the new Excel file.

Comment: @Ralph thanks for the suggestion. That works and I can also use the immediate window to refer to a cell which will return a value on the locked sheet. Unfortunately 'carbon copying' the sheet won't really work as I there could be up-to 6 sheets with n number of rows. You've given me some food for thought though. Thanks.

Comment: Doing that one 6 sheets and N rows is easy with loops: `For each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and then another loop or `for ... next` statement to iterate through the rows.... done.